# How to execute a function inside a python script on a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following script in a string in Python that I get through API:

```
script = """
import logging        
    
def run():
    logging.info('Function Executed')
    return "SUCCESS"
"""
```

And what I need is to run the `run` function of this script and retrieve its return in Python.
I tried something that way with `eval` and `exec` but was unsuccessful:

with `eval`:

```
script = """
import logging        
    
def run():
    logging.info('Function Executed')
    return "SUCCESS"
"""

response = eval(script).run()
```

with `exec`:

```
script = """
import logging        
    
def run():
    logging.info('Function Executed')
    return "SUCCESS"
"""

exec script
response = run()
```

Note: I need this execution to be in a request context so that there are no concurrent executions of the `run` method.

Updated:
Note: It is a specific and internal use case, it will not be an API exposed to the internet. The use case is for an AntiFraud rules engine written in Python. The rules are written by analysts and stored in a database in the format I wrote in the question. The proposal of the engine is to seek and execute these rules written in Python.

Comment: `that I get through API` ... this sounds like a potential source for a major script injection attack.  Why are you running Python code which you receive from an API endpoint?

Comment: This is a very bad idea, from a security standpoint. You should _not_ automatically execute code you get from an API.

Comment: It is a specific and internal use case, it will not be an API exposed to the internet.  The use case is for an AntiFraud rules engine written in Python.  The rules are written by analysts and stored in a database in the format I wrote in the question.  The function of the engine is to seek and execute these rules written in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is not a good idea to do so from security viewpoint.

But, if you want to do it, you can do it this way:

```py
import os

script = """
print("Executed!")
"""

with open('script.py','w') as fhand:
    fhand.write(script)

os.system('python script.py')
```

You can write the string in `script` to another `*.py` file and then run that script.

Edit:
If you want to execute the function, you could do somthing like this:

```py
import os

scriipt = """
def hello():
    print('Executed')
"""

with open('script.py','w') as fhand:
    fhand.write(scriipt)

import script  //which is the name of the python file

script.hello()
```

One downside, you should know the name of the function.

Comment: Mayank, how do I execute the function inside this file in an isolated context per request?

Comment: @JoãoRafaelCamposdaSilva Updated the answer